# Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED e: Could not load module <Error module> I am getting this error

Tags: kotlin

Ran into the error: > Task :app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin FAILED
e: Could not load module  while making my build.

Here is the source code: https://github.com/FireMagicKev/Pokedex

I tried searching Google and just came up with a file import was wrong and people had to manually change files? It was not specific enough for me to understand what to do for my project.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Found it was the gson that was corrupting the data and was outdated. Had to update it to kotlinx.serialization.

It is also important to update the "Any" in the list files.

My original code reflects the changes.